# Check engine light is on

Tags: engine, electrical, warning-light

As I research the make and model of my car, a '96 Mitsubishi Legnum I find that the check engine light coming on is a regular occurrence. Any ideas or a check list of possible reasons that I may be able to use to eliminate this problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Having the codes read is the best way to find out why the light keeps recurring.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself an OBDII code reader. Buy a cheap one you don't need anything special. I've seen them as low as $15 Cdn and wouldn't pay anything more than $30 Cdn.

Plug it in and follow the directions.

[OBD2 from Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011Q18D14)

It plugs into this thing here...

[image: OBD2Port]

Once you know what the code is you can clear it and then go find out what it means.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you to check levels etc under the bonnet. Once the light is on then something needs your attention.

If you can get the codes read, then that may help us point you in a direction - as just the light is on does not narrow down which system.

It probably is just coincidence that this has started to happen at the same time that you start your research.

Comment: OK so I have checked the tranny levels, steering, and brake levels, but how would I go about getting the codes checked? I am hoping that it is coincidence, not bad choice. However I would love to be able to get this car to a reliable point.

Comment: To read the codes you have a couple of options: 1 go to a dealer / garage / specialist, 2 purchase a code reader and then use it to read the codes, 3 some vehicles are able to display codes on the dash, but this is very vehicle specific and, if it is available, the method will be in the manual.

Comment: Thanx Mike, I appreciate yur help...

Comment: @SolarMike - actually, the method may not be in the manual. My 1989 Opel Vectra had a mode where it blinks the trouble code light (e.g. code 35 = 3 blinks, 1 pause, 5 blinks) according to the errors. This mode was activated by shorting two pins in a connector. The method definitely wasn't in the manual! Allowed me to not use a code reader, so I wish all cars had this same feature today.

Comment: @juhist owner's manual or factory / workshop manual?

Comment: Ah yes, it was owner's manual. Of course workshop manual will have the method in it.